# Training PyTorch GAN fills RAM in Jupyter Notebook, but not in Colab

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am running [this code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ExKu5QxKxbeO7QnVGQx6nzFaGxz0FDP3?usp=sharing#scrollTo=nqKLmvRJVnc3) locally and trying to implement a GAN. It is the simplest GAN one can think of, (please refer to [this site](https://debuggercafe.com/generating-mnist-digit-images-using-vanilla-gan-with-pytorch/)) moreover the dataset is the MNIST, which I have already used previously leading to no memory issue at all so far.

The local environment is built according to the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.7.0-cuda11.0-cudnn8-runtime

RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN pip install jupyter jupyterlab pandas numpy scikit-learn cython matplotlib seaborn optuna plotly imageio
EXPOSE 8886 8887 8888 8889

ENTRYPOINT jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password='' --port 8886
```

And the container, created using this image, is accessed using the Jupyter Notebook. I set the container to have a default maximum RAM memory to 24GB.

I used it for also other tasks, also really intensive ones (e.g. running hyperparameters optimization), and I have never had any problem. However, when trying to train the network:

```
# create the noise vector
noise = create_noise(sample_size, nz)

generator.train()
discriminator.train()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    loss_g = 0.0
    loss_d = 0.0
    for bi, data in tqdm(enumerate(train_loader), total=int(len(train_data)/train_loader.batch_size)):
        image, _ = data
        image = image.to(device)
        b_size = len(image)
        # run the discriminator for k number of steps
        for step in range(k):
            data_fake = generator(create_noise(b_size, nz)).detach()
            data_real = image
            # train the discriminator network
            loss_d += train_discriminator(optim_d, data_real, data_fake)
        data_fake = generator(create_noise(b_size, nz))
        # train the generator network
        loss_g += train_generator(optim_g, data_fake)

    # create the final fake image for the epoch
    generated_img = generator(noise).cpu().detach()
    # make the images as grid
    generated_img = make_grid(generated_img)
    # save the generated torch tensor models to disk
    save_generator_image(generated_img, f"outputs/gen_img{epoch}.png")
    images.append(generated_img)
    epoch_loss_g = loss_g / bi # total generator loss for the epoch
    epoch_loss_d = loss_d / bi # total discriminator loss for the epoch
    losses_g.append(epoch_loss_g)
    losses_d.append(epoch_loss_d)
    
    print(f"Epoch {epoch} of {epochs}")
    print(f"Generator loss: {epoch_loss_g:.8f}, Discriminator loss: {epoch_loss_d:.8f}")
```

When training the network, the container starts filling the RAM memory quickly (this behavior can be checked through the "stats" window in Docker Desktop), finally running out of it and forcing me to stop and eventually remove the container. It happens both when splitting the code into several cells to be run, and when creating a unique `*.py` file finally running it as it is in the Colab link.

As a possible fix, I have tried to collect the garbage at the end of every training step with `gc.collect()`, and to delete `data_fake`, `data_real`, `image_batch`, `generated_img` but nothing changes.

However, surprisingly, this does **not** occur in Google Colab and I cannot explain why. Any hint on how to fix, or how to check what step occupies the most memory, besides the suggestion of running it remotely?

EDIT: I checked the Python's versions, and Colab uses Python 3.7.11, whereas my container has Python 3.8.8. I do not know if this might be an explanation

Comment: Do you detach the output of ``train_generator`` and ``train_discriminator``? Otherwise, you are accumulating the losses of all batches and all epochs without detaching them in ``losses_g`` and ``losses_d``. PyTorch will retain all computation graphs and gradient information this way filling up your RAM. Try calling ``loss_g.detach()``.

Comment: I have just tried both `loss_g.detach()` and `loss_d.detach()` , but no improvement and RAM keeps being filled during training.

Comment: When did you call ``detach``? You should call it in the inner loop. BTW ``detach`` is out-of-place meaning it returns the detached tensor and does not modify the original one.

Comment: I called  `loss_g.detach()` and `loss_d.detach()` right after the line:

`loss_g += train_generator(optim_g, data_fake)`

with the indentation that calls them once per epoch.

Comment: Ok, but did you assign the result of ``detach`` back to ``loss_g``? Like ``loss_g = loss_g.detach()``. Otherwise, it will not do anything.

Comment: I see. I have tried to reassign the result and indeed now it does not seem to fill up the memory anymore. Sorry, I had not understood what you meant in your second message, should have checked the doc. Thank you, now it's solved!
The only thing missing is why, and how, Colab is able to fix this issue automatically

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe Colab has just a much larger RAM.